# Idiom for someone who works fast without paying attention to the quality?

Tags: pejorative-language, idiom-requests

Is there any idiom or any suitable words for someone who works fast without paying attention to the quality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Quick and dirty"

> *l am not interested in a quick and dirty job. I want it done right. The contractor made a lot of money on quick and dirty projects that would never last very long.*

Comment: "Quick and dirty" is an idiom, with a largely positive connotation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The following phrase is a very well-known proverb and is often said in cases when we advise someone against rushing a task or performing it poorly.

**If a thing is worth doing, it's worth doing well.**

Proverb: [If you decide to do something, do it as well as you possibly can](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/If+a+thing+is+worth+doing,+it%27s+worth+doing+well)

> Bruce never did sloppy work. He believed that if something is worth
>   doing, it's worth doing well.

A suitable word that describes someone who works fast but carelessly is the adjective **[slapdash](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/slapdash)**

> He gets his work done quickly, but he's very slapdash

Answer (score 2):

I would simply reverse a common phrase and use, **quantity over quality**.

Answer (score 1):

**Shoveling** is often used in this context: "he's just shoveling it out."

Answer (score 1):

You might say that they are doing *sloppy* or *shoddy* work. You could also describe them as a *bodger*, particularly if their job involves making or repairing something.

Answer (score 1):

As an idiom: ***[give something a lick and a promise](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+a+lick+and+a+promise)***

> *(American & Australian old-fashioned)* to do a job or piece of work quickly and not carefully
>
> *We didn't have time to do much clearing up in the yard - just gave the grass a lick and a promise.*

It is old-fashioned but it is still used today. Sometimes used as "a lick and a promise".

---

Also, as an idiom: ***[once-over-lightly](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/once-over-lightly)***

> **1.** *Fig.* a quick and careless treatment. (A noun. Said of an act of cleaning, studying, examination, or appraisal.)
>
> *Bill gave his geometry the once-over-lightly and then quit studying. Ann, you didn't wash the dishes properly. They only got a once-over-lightly.*
>
> **2.** Fig. cursory; in a quick and careless manner. (An adverb.)
>
> *Tom studied geometry once-over-lightly. Ann washed the dishes once-over-lightly.*